# I am trying to use microsoft cognitive search api for web results

Tags: api, search-engine, azure-cognitive-services

```
final String accountKey = "***********************";
    final String bingUrlPattern ="https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=bill gates"; 


    String query = URLEncoder.encode("'what      is omonoia'", Charset.defaultCharset().name());
    String bingUrl = String.format(bingUrlPattern, query);

    String accountKeyEnc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());

    URL url = new URL(bingUrl);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);

    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
        String inputLine;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        JSONObject d = json.getJSONObject("d");
        JSONArray results = d.getJSONArray("results");
        int resultsLength = results.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < resultsLength; i++) {
            final JSONObject aResult = results.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(aResult.get("Url"));
        }
    }
}
```

Code returns 400 error code while execution.
 It seems format of url pattern is wrong. Please suggest.
 Also how can can specify format to be in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying your auth incorrectly.  You'll want the following instead:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", accountKey);
```

You'll also want to change how the URL is constructed, since you've hard-coded the query to 'bill gates'.

```
final String bingUrlPattern ="https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/search?q=%s";
```

You may find the [API console](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console) helpful.